# Can python regex negate a list of words?

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I have to match all the alphanumeric words from a text.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "hello world!! how are you?"
>>> final_list = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+", text)
>>> final_list
['hello', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you']
>>>
```

This is fine, but further I have few words to negate i.e. the words that shouldn't be in my final list.

```
>>> negate_words = ['world', 'other', 'words']
```

A bad way to do it

```
>>> negate_str = '|'.join(negate_words)
>>> filter(lambda x: not re.match(negate_str, x), final_list)
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

But i can save a loop if my very first regex-pattern can be changed to consider negation of those words. I found negation of characters but i have words to negate, also i found regex-lookbehind in other questions, but that doesn't help either.

Can it be done using python re?

**Update**

My text can span a few hundered lines. Also, list of negate_words can be lengthy too.

Considering this, **is using regex for such task, correct in the first place??** Any suggestions??

Comment: is there a lot of `negate_words` ?

Comment: @bitsMiz Yes, there can be many negate words. And Text can span few hundered lines too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a clean way to do this using regular expressions.  The closest I could find was bit ugly and not exactly what you wanted:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\b(?:world|other|words)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b", text)
['hello', '', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Why not use Python's sets instead.  They are very fast:

```
>>> list(set(final_list) - set(negate_words))
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

If order is important, see the reply from @glglgl below.  His list comprehension version is very readable.  Here's a fast but less readable equivalent using [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#module-itertools):

```
>>> negate_words_set = set(negate_words)
>>> list(itertools.ifilterfalse(negate_words_set.__contains__, final_list))
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Another alternative is the build-up the word list in a single pass using [re.finditer](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
>>> result = []
>>> negate_words_set = set(negate_words)
>>> result = []
>>> for mo in re.finditer(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+", text):
    word = mo.group()
    if word not in negate_words_set:
         result.append(word)

>>> result
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that word order will be lost.

Comment: `[i for i in final_list if i not in negate_words_set]`

Comment: @raymond, Ah!! you sure about re? But +1 anyway, I can definitely replace my filter function with sets as you mentioned.

Comment: @simplyharsh I added in a variant using regexes but it isn't fully worked out and isn't elegant.  The idea is to let the stop list words match before the group describing the words to be included.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is worth trying pyparsing for this:

```
>>> from pyparsing import *

>>> negate_words = ['world', 'other', 'words']
>>> parser = OneOrMore(Suppress(oneOf(negate_words)) ^ Word(alphanums)).ignore(CharsNotIn(alphanums))
>>> parser.parseString('hello world!! how are you?').asList()
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Note that `oneOf(negate_words)` must be before `Word(alphanums)` to make sure that it matches earlier.

Edit: Just for the fun of it, I repeated the exercise using [lepl](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/) (also an interesting parsing library)

```
>>> from lepl import *

>>> negate_words = ['world', 'other', 'words']
>>> parser = OneOrMore(~Or(*negate_words) | Word(Letter() | Digit()) | ~Any())
>>> parser.parse('hello world!! how are you?')
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't ask uselessly too much to regex.
Instead, think to generators.

```
import re

unwanted = ('world', 'other', 'words')

text = "hello world!! how are you?"

gen = (m.group() for m in re.finditer("[a-zA-Z0-9]+",text))
li = [ w for w in gen if w not in unwanted ]
```

And a generator can be created instead of **li**, also